# Grep regular expression stop after first match

Tags: grep

I am trying to figure out what the grep syntax would be to get one\unique result of a search.

For example :

> grep "^SEVERE"  server.out

SEVERE: Cannot connect repository, Error occurred when calling service PING_SERVER. 
SEVERE: Cannot connect repository, Error occurred when calling service PING_SERVER. 
SEVERE: Cannot connect repository, Error occurred when calling service PING_SERVER.

I would like the output to show only the first find of the that occurrence.

Any Help would be great!

- tcwbot

Answer (score 3, accepted):

GNU grep 2.16 which comes with cygwin has this option (from 'man grep'):

```
-m NUM, --max-count=NUM
          Stop reading a file after NUM matching lines.  If the  input  is
          standard  input  from a regular file, and NUM matching lines are
          output, grep ensures that the standard input  is  positioned  to
          just  after the last matching line before exiting, regardless of
          the presence of trailing context lines.  This enables a  calling
          process  to resume a search.  When grep stops after NUM matching
          lines, it outputs any trailing context lines.  When  the  -c  or
          --count  option  is  also  used,  grep  does  not output a count
          greater than NUM.  When the -v or --invert-match option is  also
          used, grep stops after outputting NUM non-matching lines.
```

So try:

```
$ grep -m 1 "^SEVERE" server.out
```